# Maximizing a parametric integral over the unit sphere

Tags: real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

I am trying to compute the nonnegative quantity
$$
\underset{y\in\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}{\sup}\int_{0}^{t}(\Vert A(\tau)y\Vert_{1}- \Vert A(\tau)y\Vert_{q})d\tau, \quad 1 < q < \infty
$$
where $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. For each $\tau\in[0,t]$, the given matrix $A(\tau)\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times d}$, $m\leq d$, is entry-wise nonnegative smooth function of $\tau$, and has full row rank $m$.

From numerical experiments, it seems there are $2^{m}$ unit vectors $y_{\max}$, which differ by plus-minus sign permutations among components, achieving the same global maximum.

**Question:** Is there an argument that leads to analytical formula for the maximum value? The problem comes from computing the Hausdorff distance between two convex sets.

**Added 05/27/2022:** I tried to understand the simpler case when the full row rank matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times d}$ is constant, i.e., computing
$$
\underset{y\in\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}{\sup}(\Vert Ay\Vert_{1}- \Vert Ay\Vert_{q}), \quad 1 < q < \infty
$$
as a function of the matrix $A$, and wasn't successful.